# realloc but only first few bytes is meaningful

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc, libc

Assume I have used `ptr = malloc(old_size);` to allocate a memory block with `old_size` bytes. Only the first `header_size` bytes is meaningful. I'm going to increase the size to `new_size`.

`new_size` is greater than `old_size` and `old_size` is greater than `header_size`.

before:

```
/- - - - - - - old_size - - - - - - - \
+===============+---------------------+
 \-header_size-/
```

after:

```
/- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - new_size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\
+===============+------------------------------------------------------------+
\- header_size-/
```

I don't care what is stored after `ptr + header_size` because I'll read some data to there.

#### method 1: go straight to `new_size`

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);
```

#### method 2: shrink to `header_size` and grow to `new_size`

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, header_size);
ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);
```

#### method 3: allocate a new memory block and copy the first `header_size` bytes

```
void *newptr = malloc(new_size);
memcpy(newptr, ptr, header_size);
free(ptr);
ptr = newptr;
```

Which is faster?

Comment: @nos I'll write some data beyond `header_size` after reallocation so I don't care what is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost certainly depends on the values of `old_size`, `new_size` and `header_size`, and also it depends on the implementation. You'd have to pick some values and measure.

1) is probably best in the case where `header_size == old_size-1 && old_size == new_size-1`, since it gives you the best chance of the single `realloc` being basically a no-op. (2) should be only very slightly slower in that case (2 almost-no-ops being marginally slower than 1).

3) is probably best in the case where `header_size == 1 && old_size == 1024*1024 && new_size == 2048*1024`, because the `realloc` would have to move the allocation, but you avoid copying 1MB of data you don't care about. (2) should be only very slightly slower in that case.

2) is probably best when `header_size` is much smaller than `old_size`, and `new_size` is in a range where it's reasonably likely that the `realloc` will relocate, but *also* reasonably likely that it won't. Then you can't predict which of (1) and (3) it is that will be very slightly faster than (2).

In analyzing (2), I have assumed that realloc downwards is approximately free and returns the same pointer. This is not guaranteed. I can think of two things that can mess you up:

- realloc downwards copies to a new allocation
- realloc downwards splits the buffer to create a new chunk of free memory, but then when you realloc back up again the allocator *doesn't* merge that new free chunk straight back onto your buffer again in order to return without copying.

Either of those could make (2) significantly more expensive than (1). So it's an implementation detail whether or not (2) is a good way of hedging your bets between the advantages of (1) (sometimes avoids copying anything) and the advantages of (3) (sometimes avoids copying too much).

Btw, this kind of idle speculation about performance is more effective in order to tentatively explain your observations, than it is to tentatively predict what observations we would make in the unlikely event that we actually cared enough about performance to test it.

Furthermore, I suspect that for large allocations, the implementation might be able to do even a relocating `realloc` without copying anything, by re-mapping the memory to a new address. In which case they would all be fast. I haven't looked into whether implementations actually do that, though.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `malloc` (for the whole block) nor `realloc` (for the space beyond the size of the old block when increasing the size) guarantee what the memory you receive will contain so, if you want those excess bytes set to zero (for example), you'll have to do it yourself with something like:

```
// ptr contains current block.
void *saveptr = ptr;
ptr = realloc (ptr, new_size);
if (ptr == NULL) {
    // do something intelligent like recover saveptr and exit.
}
memset (ptr + header_size, 0, new_size - header_size);
```

However, since you've stated that you don't care about the content beyond the header, the fastest is almost certainly a single `realloc` since that's likely to be optimised under the covers.

Calling it twice for contraction and expansion, or calling `malloc-new/memcpy/free-old` is very unlikely to be as efficient though, as with all optimisations, you should *measure, don't guess!*

Keep in mind that `realloc` doesn't necessarily have to copy your memory at all. If the expansion can be done in place, then an intelligent heap manager will just increase the size of the block without copying anything, such as:

```
+-----------+   ^        +-----------+ <- At same address,
| Old block |   | Need   | New block |      no copying
|           |   | this   |           |      involved.
+-----------+   | much   |           |
| Free      |   | now.   |           |
|           |   v        +-----------+
|           |            | Free      |
|           |            |           |
+-----------+            +-----------+
```

Comment: Huh? Of course `realloc()` guarantees that the new memory will contain as much as will fit from the old block.

Comment: @unwind: I meant beyond the old boundary, not the memory in the old block. I'll clarify.

Comment: @lqs, since you've stated in a comment that you don't care what the non-header contains, I've simplified my answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

That probably depends on what the sizes are and if copying is needed.

Method 1 will copy everything contained in the old block - but if you don't do that too often, you won't notice.

Method 2 will only copy what you need to keep, as you discard everything else beforehand.

Method 3 will copy unconditionally, while the others only copy if the memory block cannot be resized where it is.

Personally, I would prefer method 2 if you do this quite often, or method 1 if you do it more seldom. Respectively, I would profile which of these will be faster.

Comment: Method 2 is the only one that *both* avoids a copy entirely, if there is free space after the block, *and* otherwise copies only the minimum memory. Method 1 is the most efficient in the best case, but possibly also the the least efficient in the worst case. It does depend now much data we're talking about whether the extra function overheads are worthwhile.

Comment: @ams Are there actually `realloc` implementations that consider free blocks after the block about to be `realloc`'ed? It seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @pmr: even if they don't try to merge blocks, in the case where `new_size - old_size` is small there might be free space at the end of the block that can be used to satisfy the new size, due to `old_size` having been rounded up.

Comment: @pmr Why wouldn't the implementation extend an allocation into following free space, if there is some? Sure, somebody has to implement it that way, but there's a lot of smart people out there! In reality though, you can't even assume that *reducing* the size of the allocation won't result in a copy.

Comment: @pmr At least some implementations of `malloc` use `mmap` for allocations greater than one page (typically 4KiB), so extending the size of the allocation is almost a no-op. It depends how crowded the address space is, but on a 64-bit machine that's probably not a problem.